FormAssembly to Lead Conversion Process
I have a formassembly form connected to our salesforce that creates a lead using the information from the form. The lead owner is chosen based off of our lead assignment rules.
However, the lead's record type is based off of the lead owner's default lead record type even when I put in the formassembly connector that it should be a specific record type. Our users have to constantly change the record type of the lead to show the correct information. This gets tedious when we have multiple lead processes and record types so changing the all lead owners' default record types wouldn't help. This also happens during conversion where it always converts it into the lead owners' default record type for contacts.
Is there a way that I can control the record types?
We also have a lot of required fields and validation rules on our client contact record that prevents proper conversion so we have have told our users to just use the lead information and not the conversion function.
Is there an alternative process where conversion is easier for our users?
Can we modify the page layout for the lead conversion page and show more information? Such as if there is a merge available, it shows some fields from the contact record already in our database. And if it is a new contact, it allows our user to select a certain contact record type?

